# SQL Server: The requested properties cannot be supported`

Tags: sql-server, django

I'm trying to setup an SQL connection (using django-mssql).

I'm using the following connection string:

> 'DATA_SOURCE=\,1337;Initial
>   Catalog=*****;UID=******;PWD=******;PROVIDER=sqlncli10;MARS
>   Connection=True'

Which results in a connection error:

> The requested properties cannot be supported

I'm not sure what 'requested properties' are meant here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not enough information in your question. Which version of SQL server? Which version of Django? Which version of django-mssql? What are your database settings (obscure the password)? Is there a stack trace to go along with that error?

Answer (score -1):

Use "Server" or "Data Source" not "DATA_SOURCE"

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012 for more

Comment: The connection string is generated by django-mssql database backend. And I have a similar connection string working with another database.
Which would suggest the DATA_SOURCE attribute is not the source of the error.